# Передача нескольких данных в представление View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Хочу передать данные с двух таблиц из бд но не могу понять как в View передать сразу два списка.
Вот код:

```
public IActionResult AllCustomers()
        {
            //Два списка которые нужно передать в view
            db.Custumers.ToList();
            db.Founders.ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс-модель с двумя свойствами:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    List<Founder> Founders { get; set; }
}
```

Использование:

```
var someModel = new SomeModel
{
    Customers = db.Customers.ToList(),
    Founders = db.Founders.ToList()
};

return View(someModel);
```

Самое сложное тут - придумать хорошее название этой модели.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я пробовал то же самое но в итог когда я  в самом представлении в цикле: `@foreach (var customer in Model)` ссылаюсь на элемент: `@customer.Customers.id` то сами элементы этих двух моделей она не видит. Может ссылка на модель не правильная ? :`@model IEnumerable<MyTest.Models.SomeModel>`

Comment: @Al-Tamir - во вьюхе должно быть `@model MyTest.Models.SomeModel`

Comment: Точняк, а то за чем списку IEnumerable.Спасибо •́ ‿ •̀